# How to limit an else statement? - Javascript game

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement, optimization

I'm looking for an explanation on how I would properly implement a 'button' (square) that you would stand on, which would change the background color. I've successfully implemented the if statement, which changes the background, but when I add an else statement to change it back to normal when you are not on the button, it runs repeatedly without stopping.

The same goes for another obstacle I have that makes you move slower when standing on it. When you're not on the obstacle, it's constantly changing the variable rather than changing it back once.

```js
var gravity = 30;
var jumpSpeed = 17;
var playerYSpeed = 7;

Player.prototype.moveY = function(step, level, keys, pos) {
  this.speed.y += step * gravity;
  var motion = new Vector(0, this.speed.y * step);
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(motion);
  var obstacle = level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size);
  var lastObstacle = null;

  if (obstacle) {
      if (keys.up && this.speed.y > 0)
        this.speed.y = -jumpSpeed;
      else
        this.speed.y = 0;
    } else {
      this.pos = newPos;
    }
  if (obstacle === "lava") {
    this.pos = new Vector(6.5, 18.5);
  }
  if (obstacle === "bouncer") {
    this.pos = newPos + 20;
    console.log('bounce');
  }
  else {
    gravity = 30;
  }
  if (obstacle === "ice") {
    playerXSpeed = 0.5;
    console.log('slow speed');
  }
  else if (obstacle !== lastObstacle){
    playerXSpeed = 7;
    console.log('norm speed');
  }
  var changeBackground = document.getElementsByClassName('background');
  if (obstacle === "blind") {
      changeBackground[0].style.background = 'white';
      console.log('purple');
    }
  else if (obstacle !== lastObstacle){
      changeBackground[0].style.background = 'blue';
      console.log('blue');
  }
};
```

The 'blind' obstacle is supposed to change the background only when you are standing on it, and when you are off it's supposed to revert to normal. Same for the ice.

So how would you make this more like a 'switch on' - 'switch off' scenario?

Comment: Shouldn't `obstacle` be called `surface`? Then again I have no idea what 'blind' is supposed to signify

Comment: ...or better switch to object and event based coding like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287108/can-i-create-a-custom-event-in-javascript-for-an-object-i-created

Comment: Can you please post more of your code so we can see from where is the if else statement called? It seems that your code is making an infinite loop. And why do you need constantly changing the background variable rather than changing it once, when the player stepped away from it?

Comment: @user3362334 I don't want it to change constantly. I just wanted it to change once you step on it, and once when you step off. I update the code with the entire function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand your code correctly it is in some loop function.

You could add a variable "lastObstacle" and check whether the current obstacle is different. (else if (lastObstacle !== obstacle)

```js
var gravity = 30;
var jumpSpeed = 17;
var playerYSpeed = 7;
var lastObstacle = null;

Player.prototype.moveY = function(step, level, keys, pos) {
  this.speed.y += step * gravity;
  var motion = new Vector(0, this.speed.y * step);
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(motion);
  var obstacle = level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size);

  if (obstacle) {
      if (keys.up && this.speed.y > 0)
        this.speed.y = -jumpSpeed;
      else
        this.speed.y = 0;
    } else {
      this.pos = newPos;
    }
  if (obstacle === "lava") {
    this.pos = new Vector(6.5, 18.5);
  }
  if (obstacle === "bouncer") {
    this.pos = newPos + 20;
    console.log('bounce');
  }
  else {
    gravity = 30;
  }
  if (obstacle === "ice") {
    playerXSpeed = 0.5;
    console.log('slow speed');
  }
  else if (obstacle !== lastObstacle){
    playerXSpeed = 7;
    console.log('norm speed');
  }
  var changeBackground = document.getElementsByClassName('background');
  if (obstacle === "blind") {
      changeBackground[0].style.background = 'white';
      console.log('purple');
    }
  else if (obstacle !== lastObstacle){
      changeBackground[0].style.background = 'blue';
      console.log('blue');
  }
  lastObstacle = obstacle;
};
```

(comment: snippet will probaby not work.)

PS: I made a little mistake that i corrected now:

```js
var gravity = 30;
var jumpSpeed = 17;
var playerYSpeed = 7;
var lastObstacle = null;

Player.prototype.moveY = function(step, level, keys, pos) {
  this.speed.y += step * gravity;
  var motion = new Vector(0, this.speed.y * step);
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(motion);
  var obstacle = level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size);

  if (obstacle) {
      if (keys.up && this.speed.y > 0)
        this.speed.y = -jumpSpeed;
      else
        this.speed.y = 0;
    } else {
      this.pos = newPos;
    }
  if (obstacle === "lava") {
    this.pos = new Vector(6.5, 18.5);
  }
  if (obstacle === "bouncer") {
    this.pos = newPos + 20;
    console.log('bounce');
  }
  else {
    gravity = 30;
  }
  if (obstacle === "ice") {
    playerXSpeed = 0.5;
    console.log('slow speed');
  }
  else if (lastObstacle === "ice"){
    playerXSpeed = 7;
    console.log('norm speed');
  }
  var changeBackground = document.getElementsByClassName('background');
  if (obstacle === "blind") {
      changeBackground[0].style.background = 'white';
      console.log('purple');
    }
  else if (lastObstacle === "blind"){
      changeBackground[0].style.background = 'blue';
      console.log('blue');
  }
  lastObstacle = obstacle;
};
```

I changed the two occurences of `lastObstacle !== obstacle`.

Edit 2: This works that way: It executes the else-if block only if you are now not on an ice/blind block and your were on an ice/blind block before.

Comment: Sorry, I could've explained it better. There is no loop in the function. The function is called to check what surface the player is on. I'll update the post with the full function.

Comment: @KyleSteward But when is this function called?

Comment: It's just called constantly to check whether the player jumps on one of the obstacles.

Comment: I updated my answer to your code. You need to define lastObstacle outside the function to prevent it from being reset every time. I cannot test this code but I suppose that it works.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Now I'm gonna ask how that works so I can actually understand what I'm doing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, @PaulStrobach. I added a nested if inside the if statements to check if the background is already white, so it doesn't continuously re-initialize that as well. Will add it to the ice statement as well. Thanks again!